# Parsing a localstorage object gives uncaught syntax error?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage

I'm trying to save numbers given by Math.random. I save them in array which gets saved into localStorage. I then want to append each new array of numbers when Math.random is used. It's easier if you [view the code I tried wrting](http://jsfiddle.net/LYhLW/1/%20%22view%20the%20code%20I%20tried%20writing).

```
var nums = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
    nums.push(" " + num);
}
console.log(nums);

function appendToStorage(name, data) {
    var old = localStorage.getItem(name);
    if (old === null) old = "";
    localStorage.setItem(name, old + JSON.stringify(data));
}

if (localStorage.num) {
    appendToStorage('num', nums);
} else {
    localStorage.setItem("num", JSON.stringify(nums));
}
var nums2 = localStorage.getItem("num");
console.log(nums2);
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = JSON.parse(nums2);
```

This doesn't work, though. Console says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`
This error will work if you remove the `JSON.parse` on `getElementById`. I want it to be parsed, though, so the numbers are more easily viewed. How can I do this?

Comment: The code doesn't throw any Error when I try it, are you sure you don't have any old data in the local storage?

Comment: It only throws an error in console, so in chrome you need to do inspect element and go to console... if it's not going for you, that's strange. I'm hoping these answers below will fix it, I haven't gotten to try them yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply append a valid JSON string to another valid JSON string you don't get a valid JSON string. For example:

```
var myJSON = '{"thing": "data"}';  // valid
myJSON = myJSON + myJSON; // myJSON is now '{"thing": "data"}{"thing": "data"}', not valid
```

To do this reliably you'll need to parse your retrieved JSON, update the result, then `stringify` it again before storing it in `localStorage`.

```
function appendToStorage(name, data) {
    var old = localStorage.getItem(name);
    if (old === null) old = "[]";
    var newData = JSON.parse(old);
    newData.push(data);
    localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(newData));
}
```

Note that this will return an array when you parse it, and that will cause you a problem when you try to set `innerHTML`. You'll need to unpack the array to some sort of text format first (thanks to [jibsales](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1396172/jibsales) for that).

Answer (score 1):

Element.innerHTML takes a string as valid input, not an Array. May I suggest using JSON.parse(nums).join("");

Using this method would also allow you to not add the leading white space in your for loop and instead add the white space as the first parameter to the Array.join method. If you want each number on a new line, pass "\n".

Comment: Ok so I guess  I'm doing something wrong. I updated the function with the one Mike gave, and switched the Element.innerHTML to `document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = JSON.parse(nums).join("");`

I'm probably making a dumb mistake, it's late where I am, but this still gives an unexpected syntax error